# How to add dependencies for Google Docs add-on development?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to update a Google Sheets add-on that gets AWS prices (https://github.com/reeve/gs-aws-pricing-helper)

This has a dependency of https://github.com/brucemcpherson/cCacheHandler

I've created a new project on my sheet and added all of the scripts from the AWS Pricing project. Using a function then fails with

> Error
> ReferenceError: "cCacheHandler" is not defined. (line 48).

Any idea how this kind of dependency is installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Dependency* with "*Library Key*" refers to **[library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)** (note: in new editor this field now called "*Script ID*").

If you use new or old Apps Script editor, there are instructions for both.

### For new editor

To add needed library, open your Google Apps Script project in new editor, find left sidebar (Files, Libraries, Services), and click PLUS icon (**Add a library**) next to *Libraries* section.

[image]

In opened "*Add a library*" popup window:

1. Enter "*Script ID*" in input field and click "*Look up*".
2. Click *Add*.

*Note*: in new editor you don't have to select "Version" - by default it's set to latest library version available when you add it.

### For classic editor

To add needed library, open your Google Apps Script project in classic editor and select from menu **Resources - Libraries...**

[image]

In opened "*Libraries*" popup window:

1. Enter "*Library Key*" in input field and click "*Add*".
2. Select latest library version.
3. Click *Save*.

---

### After dependency is added

To check which version of dependency you're currently using in your project, open `manifest.json` file in Apps Script editor:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "cCacheHandler",
        "version": "19",
        "libraryId": "1U6j9t_3ONTbhTCvhjwANMcEXeHXr4shgzTG0ZrRnDYLcFl3_IH2b2eAY"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can also edit these values directly, changes to manifest will be applied accordingly.